# What should I do to have a background image in the centre with low opacity?

Tags: html, css

I tried to have a background image right in the centre but with low opacity.Everytime I wrote my code it either was in the centre or with low opacity but not both simultaneously.What should I do?

```
  <head>
<style>
body { 
    background-image: url('image.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
  }
</style>
</head>
```

However,this code below is the one that provides opacity to the image but not necessarily put it in the center

```
image{
    background:url('image.png');
    background-size:100%;
    height: 250px;
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index: -1;
    filter:opacity(30%);
    -webkit-filter:opacity(30%);
}
.heading{
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
}
.color{
    height: 150px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color:#ffffff;

}
```

Comment: `image{` in css. wtf?

Comment: I actually tried combining them but whenever I include filter options it does not work on the first code

Comment: Andrey,the 'image' is a class value under <div>

Comment: Leave out the filter nonsense, and use `opacity`. And how to center an element, in this case the image, has been discussed over and over again in all possible ways, shapes and forms already, and is trivial to research.

Comment: I previously added opacity as well and it still did not work

Comment: Saying “it did not work” is like going to the doctor and szying “it hurts” without giving any additional details. Please provide the code you actually tried (both the HTML and CSS, but only the relevant parts), what you expected, and what you actually got. Providing a jsfiddle or equivalent would be a good idea too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **pseudo-element** and put it below content and then simply control opacity property like this :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background: red; /* added this to see the effect of opacity */
}

body p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
}

body:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/1000/800/);
  /* Control image position */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  /* -- */
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  /* control opacity with this*/
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vel vehicula nibh. Aliquam sit amet risus urna. Mauris ac faucibus felis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nunc dapibus urna velit,
  vitae tincidunt nulla semper quis. Morbi ullamcorper ex erat. Donec magna ipsum, efficitur ac commodo nec, dapibus at lacus. Morbi vitae maximus est, mattis ornare lorem. Sed pellentesque lacus est, non finibus lectus molestie quis. Maecenas sit amet
  consectetur massa. Sed aliquet pharetra tellus, efficitur venenatis nisl fermentum non. Nu</p>
```

Comment: Okay,but what should I do if I want the image to be specifically at the centre of the website and with low opacity?

Comment: as you can see, i applied my style to `container` so simply use `body` instead

Comment: @NehalMahmudKhan i updated my answer with background applied to body

Answer (score 0):

Declaring your background image on an element that you can maintain as a separate concern from other page elements, and further style accordingly, like adjusting the `opacity`, is a method I would recommend exploring.

**Styles attributed to the element in question:**

```
.site-bg {
  background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/1000/800/);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: .5;
  z-index: -1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center
}
```

A Code Snippet has been embedded below to demonstrate a straight-forward method to achieve the specified intended result, utilizing some common site elements and structure to add further context to the demonstration.

```js
$('#toggle-content, #gaaah-hide-it').on('click', function() {
  $('.article-body').fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.article-body {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

article {
  flex-basis: 70%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

aside {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  background: whitesmoke;
  padding: 10px;
}

.site-bg {
  background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/1000/800/);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: .5;
  z-index: -1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center
}

#toggle-content {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .7s;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 5px;
}

#toggle-content:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

#gaaah-hide-it {
  border-radius: 100%;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .7s;
  background: whitesmoke;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#gaaah-hide-it:hover {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <head>
    <!-- Only here for context to help you better understand -->
  </head>
  <div class="site-bg">
    <!-- You'll use this arbitrary div here to attribute your background-image styles to -->
  </div>
  <header>
    <h1>Here be dragons</h1>
  </header>
  <p>What will this look like with some page content? <span id="toggle-content">click here</span></p>
  <section class="article-body" style="display: none;">
    <article>
      <h2>I did a code</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Aute proident, deserunt in exercitation dolore exercitation consequat. sunt Excepteur nulla proident, sit fugiat pariatur. cupidatat laborum. ut pariatur. quis eiusmod minim incididunt voluptate enim anim laborum. aliqua. eu aliquip et nisi proident,
        cupidatat in sed esse dolore minim anim non deserunt mollit Lorem proident, magna incididunt sed et exercitation officia aliqua. nisi anim et mollit nisi dolore do aliqua. labore.</p>
      <p>Culpa tempor aliqua. cillum laborum. consectetur quis ut amet, qui ut deserunt consectetur consectetur incididunt officia proident, culpa laboris eiusmod irure sed aliquip aute sunt adipisicing reprehenderit nulla sint dolore eu quis aliquip officia
        amet, mollit quis dolor nostrud velit nostrud laboris esse nulla id ut aute et reprehenderit officia do Ut in magna laborum. nulla sed in do mollit ullamco.</p>
    </article>
    <aside>
      <span id="gaaah-hide-it" title="hide me, I'm shy">&times;</span> Some things on the side...
    </aside>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <!-- Only here for context to help you better understand -->
  </footer>
</body>
```